# The "Apply Modifiers" button not appearing

Tags: modeling

[image: SnapShot - where my apply buttons?]

I am in Object Mode and still unable to apply modifiers. the buttons are gone... what am I missing?

Comment: click on the little down arrow on the right of the camera icon, or put your cursor over the modifier and ctrl A. Not the best decision to hide the Apply function in 2.9

Comment: ha, ok. that worked. was 2.9 last night? I had the buttons visible yesterday. thanks for the help!

Comment: you must have worked with 2.8 yesterday